# How can I change the Mobile View "lookup" list threshold?

Tags: 2013, lookup-column, view, mobile, threshold

I came across a limitation when using "Mobile View" where my lookups were displaying a maximum of 20 items. This only happens in mobile view.

How can I change or remove this threshold limitation? Basically, my master list is connected via lookups to different lists (users list, location list, etc). My lookup lists has over 30 items.

This only happens on mobile view, no problems on desktop view.

Thanks.